# Rspec: How to create variable in rspec which can be accessed also from controller?

Tags: rspec

I want to make `foo` 's value available to controller as well.

abc_controller_spec.rb

```
describe "something" do 
  foo = "123"
  it "should do something" do 
    get :someaction
    .
    .
    .
  end
  .
  .
  .
end
```

abc_controller.rb

```
.
.
.
def someaction
  foo << "456"
end
```

I am getting

> Nil:Class error or no method error

.

Comment: What are you trying to describe? What your controller should exactly do?

Comment: I have a variable `current_user` in the controller action which is of type hash which gets set only when someone logins. But I just want to create `current_user` from controller spec which can also be accessed from controller. I can't even access a simple variable like `foo` as shown above.